Information push after login using NODE
I'm developing an application using React and Node. It is an ecommerce application. I have a doubt. How do I pull user information after login authentication?
Example: when I connect here on StackOverflow, how is the database pushed?
I couldn't find anything about this.

Where is your user information stored…? There is way too little detail here to affirmatively answer this question. See [ask]

Usually this is done using session cookies.

I highly recommend you to watch how to build basic authentication system with react & node videos. You can find them easily on YouTube as free.

I am encrypting the email, and storing it in localstorage, as JWT to query after login. Is it a good practice?

If you are asking about user authentication info (user), the authentication function usually returns this information on successful login.
Otherwise, if you are wondering about the profile data of the user (userProfile) (any data about the user other than authentication, for example: DoB, phone number, address, etc.), this info is usually stored as a different class/collection/schema which references the user. In this case, after successful login, you should have user returned which should contains some sort of userId that you can call the server to query for userProfile.
This is a very generic and simple flow. Based on the requirements of the application's UX, it may varies, but this would give you a rough idea of the implementation.
